# C++ code on NaCl

Tags: google-nativeclient

I've only have a simple question to ask :

Is it possible to call a local dll with NaCl ?

If the answer is yes, can anybody show me an example method to do it.

I've tried with loadlibrary but th compilation refuse the include of windows.h

Thanks a lotttttt

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: No.

Google Native Client Apps are designed to work within a Virtual Machine like sandbox environment and does not allow any external resource access. This is by design and I don't think accessing DLL will be allowed in future. This might break the promise of making it platform independent.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is not a good news, but it will save me a lot of time. So thank you again

Comment: If you can explain what dll you are trying to use, I can think of other ways... however, dll is limited to windows, so don't expect Google to add dll calling support later.
Otherwise, there are lots of libraries already ported to NaCL